A certificate chain processed but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider
I noticed that some binaries on my machine were showing up as "Invalid Signature", and looking closer at one of them in particular (Microsoft's "widgets.exe") I noticed something that seemed odd.

Why does it end up with an untrusted root certificate on a Microsoft component?
I dug as far as my limited knowledge in this area can take me, and ended up logging events in Event Viewer for Microsoft/Windows/CAPI2/Operational, and sure enough after a minute or two, the error below appears.
Is this a cause for concern? Why is this only occuring for "widgets.exe"?  And if it is a problem, how would I go about resolving this?


As described, a root certificate is on its way to the trust store but hasn’t been written yet. Then a certificate using that root certificate fails verification because the root certificate isn’t quite stored yet.

This is a home machine.  I don't have a c:\tmp so I'm confused on the commands to "root the CA certificate stored in the file rootca.cer".  What certificate am I "rooting"?  What "root CA" am I importing if I do this via certlm.msc?
